# recursive query using dapper in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dapper

I have a table(Campaign) which has self-referencing, the design looks like below;

```
   public class Campaign: SqlEntityBase
    {
        public int ParentCampaignId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Campaign ParentCampaign { get; set; }
    }
// ParentCampaignId is FK to itself
```

Now I need to retrieve a Campaign including its child,

I am trying to retrieve entity with Id=6,
[image]

Code below works fine for first child(4), but couldn't retrieve child of it(2).

There might be even more nested entities how can I retrieve all child entities...

Class:

```
 public async Task<Campaign> GetAsync(int id)
        {
            using var dbConnection = _context.CreateConnection();
            string query = @"SELECT d.[Id], d.[ParentCampaignId], d.[Name] FROM [dbo].[Campaign] d 
                             join [dbo].[Campaign] dc on 
                             d.ParentCampaignId = dc.Id 
                             WHERE d.[Id] = @Id";
                var users = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Campaign, Campaign, Campaign>(query, (p, camp) =>
                {
                    p.ParentCampaign = camp;
                    return p;
                }, splitOn: "Id,ParentCampaignId", param: new { Id = id });
                return users.FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just doing multi-mapping isn't going to work here, because you want to get recursive results.

You can use a recursive CTE query to get all parent rows. You then have two options to map them in:

- You can either map them using a `Dictionary`, by loading them in first, then iterating through them again and assigning the parent object.
- Or you can ensure the recursion returns in the correct order (by using `ORDER BY`) and just keeping track of the last one.

```cs
public class Campaign : SqlEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentCampaignId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Campaign ParentCampaign { get; set; }
}

public async Task<Campaign> GetAsync(int id)
{
    using var dbConnection = _context.CreateConnection();
    string query = @"
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.Id, d.ParentCampaignId, d.Name, 0 AS lvl
      FROM dbo.Campaign c
      WHERE c.Id = @Id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.Id, c.ParentCampaignId, c.Name, cte.lvl + 1
      FROM dbo.Campaign c
      JOIN cte on cte.ParentCampaignId = c.Id 
)
SELECT d.Id, d.ParentCampaignId, d.Name
FROM dbo.Campaign d 
ORDER BY lvl;
";
    Campaign first = null;
    Campaign previous = null;
    foreach (var user in await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Campaign>(query))
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            first = campaign;
            previous = campaign;
        }
        else
        {
            previous.Parent = campaign;
            previous = campaign;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```